# Creating an Object type based on the parameters of multiple types under a union type

Tags: typescript, types

First, I'll just provide some background info:

I have the two interfaces that both inherit off of a common base.

```js
interface Base { type: string }
interface Foo extends Base { type: "foo", name: string }
interface Bar extends Base { type: "bar", score: number }
```

I keep both in a union type so I can use it in an array that stores either of the two.

```js
type Baz = Foo | Bar;
const storage : Baz[] = [];
```

I have a type which stores all possible values of `type` for the union type, and a function that only accepts those values.

```js
type BazTypes = Baz["type"]; // "foo" | "bar"
function readBaz(type : BazTypes) { /* ... */ }
```

Now, I'm trying to make a map of functions that will parse a given object as presented by `Baz`, given its type, like so:

```js
// Expectation:
{
    "foo": (arg : Foo) => boolean, // (arg: {type: "foo", name: string}) => boolean
    "bar": (arg : Bar) => boolean, // (arg: {type: "bar", score: number}) => boolean
}

type BazMap = {
    [key in BazTypes]: (args : Baz extends {type: key} ? Baz : never) => boolean
};
const parsers : BazMap = {
    "foo": (foo /* which should be of type Foo */) => { /* ... foo.name ... */ },
    "bar": (bar /* which should be of type Bar */) => { /* ... bar.score ... */ },
}
```

However, that map instead provides the union type itself instead of the correct interface for the given type.

```js
// Reality:
{
    "foo": (arg : Foo | Bar) => boolean,
    "bar": (arg : Foo | Bar) => boolean
}

type BazMap = {
    [key in BazTypes]: (args : Baz extends {type: key} ? Baz : never) => boolean
};
const parsers : BazMap = {
    "foo": (foo /* which is Foo | Bar */) => { /* Only foo.type can be accessed. */ },
    "bar": (bar /* which is Foo | Bar */) => { /* Only bar.type can be accessed. */ },
}
```

Because of this, TypeScript does not provide me either `name` and `score` since either value does not exist in both `Foo` nor `Bar`.

I am trying to get the map as I expected. So far, I haven't been able to properly create a map that accepts the correct type.

TL;DR: **How can I create a Object type based on the parameter of a type?** (e.g. If the type is `"foo"`, it will return a parser for `Foo` (that doesn't accept `Bar`), etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `UnionToIntersection` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/8289918):

```ts
type UnionToIntersection<U> =
  (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never;

type Parsers<T extends Base> = UnionToIntersection<
  // Distributes T
  T extends any
    // {foo: (args: Foo) => boolean} but with each T
    ? {[_ in T['type']]: (args: T) => boolean}
    : never
>;

// {foo: (args: Foo) => boolean} & {bar: (args: Bar) => boolean}
type BazMap = Parsers<Baz>;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4oN4FgBQyyYAngA4QBcyGYUoA5gQL4EGiSyIoBiA9n2QQAHpBAATDGkw4CRUhWoAiGAKVzkIOAFsqNOoxZt8HaPCTSoQ0RAlT0WZHkLFyepQCM4UdS4wI+KD0QAFdtD2gjfAIFFHQAL2QAXmR+QQAfS2NY5ABVEGA+EAAVPgBJcGgsBDBCkAAeXIA+ZI0AClzrMUlkOBASZAB+ZDaAa2pcgEpkloA3PmBxZGoQCFnoaZFuqTax6lAYaGQy6aS5hfFp4bLlzTXI6PwcgAVvLCgMeuKu2x6HCBaKXydVKFU41VqRS+PzsvX6GmG2AA2gB9ZCgZDFJEAcli2IAuvjqG1vAwMNRiqcWh4BAAbCB9VguFb3KBNbJuaTxACycDIyWQrw+VXqCXZjwCIFoyG0fOoCV5-JSziIqj41DVM2QAEJtWqAHRaXQAGg0Xig1HNWt15v1-kCECiQA)

Answer (score 1):

@cherryblossom's answer is really slick, but here's a simpler way:

```
type BazMap = {
    [key in BazTypes]: (args: Baz & {type: key}) => boolean
};
```

I'm just changing the one line in your setup that's causing the error.

Your version doesn't work because your conditional `Baz extends {type: key} ? Baz : never` will always return never.  Baz is not a generic. You are asking it about your predefined union type Baz, and as a union type it does not extend the `{type: __}` properties of its members.